# Numerically find the intersection point between two sets of data.

Tags: interpolation

I'm looking for an efficient way to determine if two paths (sets of x,y coordinates) intersect at a point.

Input - (x,y) from a Mercator Projection (longitude,latitude) coordinates

Output - Intersection point

I looked at this question here: [Solve for the intersection point, given two sets of data](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168904/solve-for-the-intersection-point-given-two-sets-of-data) but there doesn't seem to be an answer.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the interpolation equation of p1=ax+b for x1,y1 points and p2=cx+d for x2,y2 points using "[Least Squares method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares)" . Then solve for p1=p2.

If you know that some intersections occurs between some "**specific points inside the bound**" and calculating intersection coordinates matters, you may fit the points you have in a polynomial (Using [Newton's Limited Divided Differences method](http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~gilbert/m243a/node6.html) or [Lagrange method](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lagrange%20ethod&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFwQFjAB&url=http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/chap6.pdf&ei=MwD9T9q1GsmM4gT_ltSIBw&usg=AFQjCNGYxB5LcvLHUvUFhBaA9c06W28w2A&cad=rja)). Then numerically solve for P1=P2 ( *Caution: This interpolation may fail for points far out of bound of the given points)*